Is my understanding of how to use CSRF tokens correct here?
I am writing a Todo App with a Vue frontend and a Django rest framework backend.
From what I have gathered, this would be a secure way for me to do authentication and authorization:
When the user tries to login, my frontend will send a POST request with the user's information. The response will be some other basic user information that I will save in my pinia application state.
But a CSRF token will also be sent back (which I believe are unique).
Then my frontend will store the CSRF token in local storage as a session.
Now when the user is in my Todo App, my frontend will have to send a GET request to get the user's tasks. Here's where I need clarifying -> In the GET request, I will pass in the CSRF token (I believe in the header) in order to get the user's tasks.
Is this the correct/secure way to use CSRF tokens for their intended purpose?

The CSRF token goes in tandem with the auth ID (session ID or REST web token). It is not of itself an auth ID. It is simply a protection against cross site request forgery.

The intended purpose of CSRF token is to make sure that request is made by a legitimate entity. A legitimate entity in this case is a your frontend app. Yes, you’ll pass it to server via HTTP header.
However, CSRF token is not an alternative to user authentication and authorization. You’ll need to implement authentication mechanism first. Without that CSRF implementation is not meaningful.

Your understanding of using CSRF tokens is on the right track, but there are some things which needed to be kept in mind.
CSRF tokens are used to prevent unauthorized requests on behalf of a user.
I would recommend this approach:

When a user logs in, Django backend include CSRF token in
the response. This token is usually set as a cookie by
Django (csrftoken by default). Also, DRF sets a session cookie (if you are using session authentication).
There is no need for the frontend to manually handle storing this token. It can be read from the cookie automatically.
In subsequent requests the frontend reads the csrftoken from the cookie and includes it in the X-CSRFToken header.
Django reads this header and authenticates a user.

Important, by defualt DRF expects the token to be in the X-CSRFToken header.


Is this the correct/secure way to use CSRF tokens for their intended purpose?

Yes. It is to be sent in the header.

When the user tries to login, my frontend will send a POST request with the user's information. The response will be some other basic user information that I will save in my pinia application state. But a CSRF token will also be sent back (which I believe are unique).

You are confusing the CSRF token with the authentication / authorization process. The Authentication / Authorization would result in another "token". It all depends on the design of your application and the authentication process. If you are using a session based application then the cookie will be set holding some session identifier. If you have a stateless application then a token identifier will be used in every request from the client app to the backend. That would not be a CSRF token but altogether another token.
Note: if you are authenticating with what is stored in a cookie then you need CSRF protection.
